# TouchableOpacity not working inside view absolute when hide and show in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

In the app I am coding right now, I  created a button, when I click that a view is showing. On that view there is a paragraph, in that "here" that link to a webpage. I need to open a website when I click that link. with position "relative" it is working but with "absolute" it is not, please help me to fix this issue. I tried lots of answers, but it doesn't work for my case!

Code:

```
 <View style={iconStyle}>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() => {
          setEnabled(!enabled);
        }}>
        <Icon />
      </Pressable>
      {enabled && (
        <View style={[styles.content, contentStyle]}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {content}{' '}
            {link && linkText && (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('clicked')}>
                <Text>here</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
```

styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 25,
    height: 20,
  },
  content: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginBottom: 30,
    top: 25,
    zIndex: 1000,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 8,
    width: 200,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: colors.green,
  },

  text: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: fonts.regular,
  },
  linkText: {
    color: colors.darkBlue,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },
});
```

[image: Screenshot when showing]

Comment: add elevation: 999 in styles.content and check

Comment: You are saying that "It is not working". What part of it is not working? Is the UI not appearing? Is the button click event not getting handled?

Comment: @Saamer The "here" is a TouchableOpacity, link to a webpage. The "here" isn't clickable, So it is not working.

Comment: @KathirpandianK not working!

Comment: The above code working fine in my system. can you share this in expo that will be more easy for us